# How to put local datacenter first in the list by swapping other datacenter in the list?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a code in which we try to put local datacenter first and shift all other datacenter but this code is throwing exception:

In my below code if `CURRENT_LOCATION` is GHI then it is throwing exception as `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
  public enum Colocation {
    ABC("ABC", 2), PQR("PQR", 3), DEF("DEF", 4), GHI("GHI", 5), ;

    ...
  }


public static List<Colocation> get() {
  List<Colocation> result = Arrays.asList(Colocation.ABC, Colocation.PQR, Colocation.DEF, Colocation.GHI);
  // first element in the list will always be the local datacenter
  Collections.swap(result, 0, CURRENT_LOCATION.get().ordinal());
  Collections.shuffle(result.subList(1, result.size()));
  return result;
}
```

What I want to do is - whatever is the `CURRENT_LOCATION`, I want to put that first in the list and rest can be random.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? the logic or the exception?

Comment: @Stultuske `Collections.swap` throws exception.

Comment: The `ordinal` of the enum is not going to be the same as the position in the list.  You should use `indexOf` (or my answer).

Comment: can u tell me how can I use indexOf here. I also need to shuffle other dc's as well.

Comment: I updated the answer with a `swap` variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
result.remove(CURRENT_LOCATION);
result.add(0, CURRENT_LOCATION);
```

Or with `swap`:

```
Collections.swap(result, 0, result.indexOf(CURRENT_LOCATION.get()));
```

Comment: can we do anything in `Collections.swap` to fix the issue? I also want to shuffle other dc's as well instead of using as it is.

Comment: You can still do the shuffle.  The `swap` just fails because you're not using the index in the list (you use `oridinal` which I think will return `5` in this case, while the list only contains 4 elements).

Comment: it is still throwing `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` exception even with indexOf.

Comment: Sorry, as you did not show the definition of `CURRENT_LOCATION` I had to guess what it represents.  I think you need to add `.get()` behind it when you use it in the `indexOf`.

Comment: @flash as you're shuffling from index 1, perhaps should you shuffle: `result.subList(1, result.size()-1)`

Comment: @MauricePerry `subList` takes a `toIndex` as 2nd parameter, so that code is correct.